# How to split one object with an array in it to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, list, object, split

I want to know if there is it is possible to split up an object into multiple objects. I have an array of objects that has another array in it and I was wondering if it is possible to split those objects for each object in the inner array. Something like:

```
obj1 = [{
  a: 1,
  b: [{c: 2},{d: 3}],
  e: 4
}]
```

to

```
obj2 =[
  {
    a: 1,
    b: [{c: 2}],
    e: 4
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: [{d: 3}],
    e: 4
  }
]
```

The object is always in this form, whether it has one object or hundreds. While some objects may have more fields in them, there is only one field with an array. Currently, I am mapping across the original array and then mapping again inside the `b` array to get to each object in there. However, I do not know where to go from there as the return object from that map would just be the original array. I do not know how to split the `b` array and map it with the original one. I thought of  {...orig, b: map()} but I don't think it will work with every object

Comment: Please indicate if the structure of your object is always like that as well as what you have tried so far to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi edited what I tried. I thought about mapping through it but struggled to put the mapping back together

Comment: @alfasin I edited the question to add more detail, but do believe I added relevant tags and specific enough title. I do not know about the MCVE part since the object I gave is what I am using but I have not thought of a working solution to my problem

Comment: Can there be other attributes in your source object than just `a` and `b`? Also, can there be more than one element in your source array?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi there can be more elements in the source object, and there can more more elements in the source array. However, I would only want to split ```b``` if it has more than one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track according to the description in your post. You have to loop through your source object, and inside each iteration, loop through your `b` array to extract each element and push it with the source iteration element in a new object into a target array.

```js
var source = [{
    a: 1,
    b: [{ c: 2 }, { d: 3 }],
    e: 4
}];

// define target as an array
var target = [];

// loop through source
source.forEach((srcElement) => {
    // loop through `b` array attribute
    srcElement.b.forEach((bElement) => {
        // push object into target with source element attributes
        // and current `b` element wrapped into an array
        target.push({
            ...srcElement,
            b: [bElement]
        });
    });
});

console.log(target);
```

NOTE: this solution assumes that on each iteration on your source object, the `b` attribute exists and is of type `Array`.

Comment: Thanks! The part of where to save the new object was driving me nuts!